# ivar check if it has been initialized and used

Tags: iphone, init, dealloc, ivar

let's say I have an instance variable
MyObject* test;

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) MyObject* test;
```

.m

```
@synthesize test;
```

I might initialize it or might now depending if I need to. If I don't need it, no point wasting on initialization.

The question is in the dealloc, is it safe to do the following check and release?

```
-(void) dealloc
{
  if ( test != nil )
  {
   [test release];
  }
{
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's perfectly fine. it is also more idiomatic to simply omit the test for `nil`.

behind the scenes, the compiler (typically*) generates a call to `objc_msgSend` or one of its variants. the implementation of `objc_msgSend` (and variants) allows the object you message to be `nil`, in the sense that it is well defined and not considered a programmer error to message `nil`. the return value of `objc_msgSend`+ variants is zeroed:

example:

```
NSString * string = nil;
NSString * copy = [string copy]; << copy will be 0/nil
NSUInteger length = [copy length]; << length will be 0
```

this means you must test for nil if returning a c++ object -- the constructor will not be invoked if the receiver is nil.

*typically, in the sense that there is a handful of c functions the compiler calls to perform messaging as well as some other common routines.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is safe. However, sending `release` to a nil won't cause any trouble, so you don't need to check for that.

Comment: I would like to add that sending any method to nil won't cause any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that. You can simply do this if you assign an **autoreleased** object to the **ivar**:

```
self.test = nil;
```

Edit:

Don't forget to call `[super dealloc]` at the end of the **dealloc** function

Answer (score 0):

It's safe but not standard practice. You can safely send messages to nil references, and this is a big part of how idiomatic Objective-C is written. Simply release the ivar:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [test release];
    // ...
```